# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI Installation Error In CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: virtualenv, setuptools, cicd, ebcli

need some help

I have a CI/CD pipeline containing the below code, the code is working fine until today.
I am getting an error while running the last row.

```
- apt-get update
- apt install python3-pip -y
- pip3 install virtualenv --break-system-packages

- apt install awscli -y

- git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup.git
- python3 ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/ebcli_installer.py
```

[error while running ebcli_installer.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sAXQ.png)

I have been tried installing specific versions of virtualenv and setuptools.
and different versions of ebcli_installer.py

pip3 install virtualenv==20.23.1 --break-system-packages
pip3 install setuptools==68.0.0 --break-system-packages